# AVFoundation - Music iOS

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I have been trying to add music to my application without particular success. I have been trying to use AVFoundation and my code is the following:

```
    //MUSIC

    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "happyDays", ofType: "wav")


    do {

        try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!))

    }
    catch {
        // process error

    }

     audioPlayer.play()
```

I do not get any error but my application boots and no music plays. Can anyone help?

Comment: Your `AVAudioPlayer` is going out of scope and being deallocated before it can play any music. Make `audioPlayer` a class instance variable to extend its life.

Comment: Yep. You are right! Can't believe I missed this :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

swift 3

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController{

    let var avPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!

     @IBAction func btnPlayPauseAudio(_ sender: UIButton){

         if self.avPlayer != nil{

            if let myAudioUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "myAudioFile", withExtension: "mp3"){

                if self.avPlayer.isPlaying{

                    self.avPlayer.pause()
                }
                else{

                    self.avPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: myAudioUrl)

                    self.avPlayer.prepareToPlay()

                    self.avPlayer.play()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```